# Core data, enitityForName nil error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

Ok so im making a gps tracking application, all the code for tracking the user is working great but now im trying to pass the data on to be saved and displayed on a summary view. I have a entity Run which is set up correctly in the model and im aware that i need to add something to the appDelegate.m didFinishLaunching with options method so that the managedObjectContext is initialised properly but i can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be MASSIVELY appreciated.

Here is my error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a
>   legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name
>   'Run''

Here is my app delegate.m

```
'import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "SummaryViewController.h"
#import "CardioViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


        return YES;
}


- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}


#pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Beginner Fitness" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Beginner Fitness.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

@end'
```

And here is my CardioViewController, i used breakpoint and the error occurs at the start of the saveRun method at the first mention of "Run" as you would expect from the error.

```
static NSString * const detailSegueName = @"NewRunDetails";


@interface CardioViewController ()<UIActionSheetDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>

@property int seconds;
@property float distance;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *locations;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Run *run;


@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *distLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *paceLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *progressImageView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *stopButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end


@implementation CardioViewController{
    NSMutableArray *locationsArray;
}
@synthesize mapView = _mapView;



- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationItem.title = _DetailModal2[0];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.timer invalidate];
}

#pragma mark - IBActions

-(IBAction)startPressed:(id)sender
{
    // hide the start UI

    // show the running UI
    self.seconds = 0;

    // initialize the timer
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(eachSecond) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    self.distance = 0;
    self.locations = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self startLocationUpdates];
}

- (IBAction)stopPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Save", @"Discard", nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}


#pragma mark - Private


- (void)saveRun
{

    Run *newRun = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Run" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    newRun.distance = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.distance];
    newRun.duration = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.seconds];
    newRun.timestamp = [NSDate date];

    NSMutableArray *locationArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (CLLocation *location in self.locations) {
        Location *locationObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Location" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        locationObject.timestamp = location.timestamp;
        locationObject.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.latitude];
        locationObject.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.longitude];
        [locationArray addObject:locationObject];
    }

    newRun.locations = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:locationArray];
    self.run = newRun;

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }


}


- (void)eachSecond
{
    self.seconds++;
    [self updateProgressImageView];
    [self updateLabels];
}

- (void)updateProgressImageView
{
    int currentPosition = self.progressImageView.frame.origin.x;
    CGRect newRect = self.progressImageView.frame;

    switch (currentPosition) {
        case 20:
            newRect.origin.x = 80;
            break;
        case 80:
            newRect.origin.x = 140;
            break;
        default:
            newRect.origin.x = 20;
            break;
    }

    self.progressImageView.frame = newRect;
}

- (void)updateLabels
{
    self.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %@",  [MathController stringifySecondCount:self.seconds usingLongFormat:NO]];
    self.distLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance: %@", [MathController stringifyDistance:self.distance]];
    self.paceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pace: %@",  [MathController stringifyAvgPaceFromDist:self.distance overTime:self.seconds]];

}

- (void)startLocationUpdates
{
    // Create the location manager if this object does not
    // already have one.
    if (self.locationManager == nil) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeFitness;

    // Movement threshold for new events.
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10; // meters

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - UIActionSheetDelegate

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    // save
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        [self saveRun];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:detailSegueName sender:nil];
        // discard
    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    for (CLLocation *newLocation in locations) {

        NSDate *eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;

        NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

        if (fabs(howRecent) < 10.0 && newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 20) {

            // update distance
            if (self.locations.count > 0) {
                self.distance += [newLocation distanceFromLocation:self.locations.lastObject];

                CLLocationCoordinate2D coords[2];
                coords[0] = ((CLLocation *)self.locations.lastObject).coordinate;
                coords[1] = newLocation.coordinate;

                MKCoordinateRegion region =
                MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, 500, 500);
                [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

                [self.mapView addOverlay:[MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:2]];
            }

            [self.locations addObject:newLocation];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolyline *polyLine = (MKPolyline *)overlay;
        MKPolylineRenderer *aRenderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:polyLine];
        aRenderer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        aRenderer.lineWidth = 3;
        return aRenderer;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    //
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

       self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
}

- (void)initilizeLocationTracking
{
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    assert(self.locationManager);

    self.locationManager.delegate = self; // tells the location manager to send updates to this object
        //
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    // start tracking the user's location
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    }


- (MKCoordinateRegion)coordinateRegionWithCenter:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)centerCoordinate approximateRadiusInMeters:(CLLocationDistance)radiusInMeters
{
    // Multiplying by MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude at the center is only approximate, since latitude isn't fixed
    //
    double radiusInMapPoints = radiusInMeters*MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(centerCoordinate.latitude);
    MKMapSize radiusSquared = {radiusInMapPoints,radiusInMapPoints};

    MKMapPoint regionOrigin = MKMapPointForCoordinate(centerCoordinate);
    MKMapRect regionRect = (MKMapRect){regionOrigin, radiusSquared}; //origin is the top-left corner

    regionRect = MKMapRectOffset(regionRect, -radiusInMapPoints/2, -radiusInMapPoints/2);

    // clamp the rect to be within the world
    regionRect = MKMapRectIntersection(regionRect, MKMapRectWorld);

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(regionRect);
    return region;
}


- (IBAction)setMap:(id)sender {
    switch (((UISegmentedControl*) sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            _mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        case 1:
            _mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;

        case 2:
            _mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:detailSegueName]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setRun:self.run];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in `saveRun` change `self.managedObjectContext` to `[(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate managedObjectContext]` ...

Comment: Cheers dude, this worked for me :), getting a array out of bounds exception now but ill try to figure out the cause before posting again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It basically means that your Core Data stack isn't set up properly when that method is called. (Likely self.managedObjectContext is nil.)

While what [thorb65 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29493642/2998) would likely work, I wouldn't recommend it. What you're trying to do with dependency injection is a much better idea, though obviously, the context hasn't been inserted (or the created) for some reason in this case. Possibly due to state restoration?

Your other option would be to set up the Core Data stack in a central location rather than the app delegate, that way it would always be set up whenever you try to use it. I've used [SLCoreDataStack](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLCoreDataStack) successfully, though there are many others and it's not difficult to create a similar structure yourself.

Comment: you're wrong. the moc is setup correctly, but he has no reference to the moc object in app delegate, so self.managedObjectContext in view controller is always nil. its not a problem to use it the way i wrote...

Comment: That's a pretty aggressive statement given that I say that your approach would work. What I disagree with is: creating the Core Data stack in the app delegate; and accessing the app delegate from anywhere else in the app.

Comment: disagree or not... appdelegate is nothing else than a singleton. if you know what you are doing and take care about threads etc its no problem to use it. I've used it in a few very simple apps for clients like this and never had problems. for bigger apps i use my own singleton for moc and entities and never had any problems with contexts or saving or threads.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CardioViewController` has a property `self.managedObjectContext`, but there's nothing in your code that shows a value being assigned to it. As a result, it's nil. You get this exception because your code attempts to use `self.managedObjectContext` when it has no value.

Your app delegate creates a managed object context, but that's not enough by itself. It doesn't automatically propagate to the view controller. In your app delegate, you need to assign the view controller's `NSManagedObjectContext` to have the same value as the one created in the app delegate. Your code doesn't show any reference to the `CardioViewController` but it's *probably* something like

```
self.cardioViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```